# Why my react html render is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a simple react component but it is not rendering the HTML on the page. Could someone please guide me where I am doing wrong?

http://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/EVNdJJ?editors=101

Thanks.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">

var newComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return (
            <h2>My Name is React</h2>
        );
    }

});

React.render(<newComponent/>,document.getElementById('content'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your component name should start with an upper-case letter. From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts
>   with an upper-case letter:

The following will render as expected:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">

var NewComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return (
            <h2>My Name is React</h2>
        );
    }

});

React.render(<NewComponent/>,document.getElementById('content'));
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks  a lot :)

Comment: If this answers your question perhaps you could mark it as the answer?